# Javascript node.js get wont give out json requested code

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, get

I'm working on a small discord bot  which requires me to do some JavaScript. I know there is some alternatives but I want to use JavaScript because of reasons. The thing is I'm trying to make a get request for JSON in node.js but It only seems to work if I put the data (chunk) into the console. If I try to concat the data I just get an empty string.

Here is my code:

```
var https = require('https');
var output;

var options = {
    host: '---',
    port: 443,
    method: 'GET',
   // json: true,
    path: '/post/index.json?limit=15',
    headers: { 'user-agent': 'DiscordLucario/1.0' }
};

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        //console.log(chunk);
        output += chunk;
    });
});
req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
req.on('end', function () {

    console.log(output);
    GTwebObject = JSON.parse(output);
    GTpictureIndex = getRandomInt(1, GTwebObject.length);
    GTpictureTags = GTwebObject[GTpictureIndex].tags;
    GTpictureURL = GTwebObject[GTpictureIndex].file_url;

});
req.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that chunk is a buffer so you need to convert it to a string before concatenating.

```
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    //console.log(chunk);
    output += chunk.toString();
});
```

Comment: I think better advice might be to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request rather than dealing with node's http/https interfaces directly anyway.

Comment: Thanks to you both. But it didnt change anything sadly. But I will keep the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the chunk data stream to String before concat.

```
var textChunk = chunk.toString('utf8');
output += textChunk
```